# Spring websocket working on local tomcat but not in server

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-websocket

I have a Spring mvc application, and I'm using websockets to communicate a phisical device that sends data with an angular 2 front end.

the architecture is like this

device ----> Spring Mvc <-----angular 2 front end

I have a datasource listener that publish to a websocket topic everytime a new message appears and I consume that topic from angular.

My problem is that this is working properly in my local tomcat install but when I upload it to a faster server it doesn't.

The main problem I'm having is that is buffering the messages and is reaching the limit and closing the websocket session.

What I noticed checking the logs is that in my local server messages come 20 milliseconds after last one is finished but in the other server sometimes are coming at the same time and they are being buffered throwing the session limit exception.

I tried setting a higher buffer  size.

Also tried a thread.sleep but it doesn't worked.

Do you have some ideas what can I do ? should I implement some kind of message queue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure that `Tomcat` is closing this connection? What is the protocol that you are using? Maybe it is closing it because `heart beats` are not send?

Comment: Catalina.out log: 
org.springframework.web.socket.handler.SessionLimitExceededException: The send buffer size 1241552 bytes for session 'ki43snl5 exceeded the allowed limit 999999
 at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.sessionLimitReached(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:162)
 at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.checkSessionLimits(ConcurrentWebSocketSessionDecorator.java:150)

Comment: Sorry that is the log I'm getting I tried changing the websocket buffer size but still the same problem,I don't believe is a tomcat issue